# How to get the highest counted column from count return

Tags: sql, oracle11g

So I just started working with SQL and I have a pretty simple problem that I can't figure out. I'm working on a practice database and I want to take a small table of books that have been ordered and find the book that has been ordered the most. So I started like this:

```
select ISBN, count(ISBN)
from orderitems
group by ISBN;
```

So this gives me a return of 2 columns the ISBN and how many times that ISBN has been in an order. From here I just want to take the highest ordered ISBN and pass it to and outside query. I thought the best way to find the most ordered ISBN would be to nest the count function inside the max function but I guess it doesn't work like that because I keep getting an error when I try to do it like this:

```
select ISBN, max(count(ISBN))
from orderitems
group by ISBN;
```

So my question is what would be the most efficient way to write this query using the max and count functions and sub queries so I will get just the most ordered ISBN returned to my outside query.
Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step by step (on concept level):

1. Count how many times each `ISBN` appears in a table.
2. Order your data in a descending manner using values calculated in Step 1
3. Limit your output to only return first row.

Actual query would look like this :

**Since Oracle 12c** this can done with `FETCH FIRST ... ROWS ONLY` syntax

```
SELECT
  ISBN
FROM
  orderitems
GROUP BY ISBN
ORDER BY COUNT(ISBN) DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
```

For Oracle versions **prior to 12c** you could for example use a `ROWNUM` pseudocolumn

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT
    ISBN
  FROM
    orderitems
  GROUP BY ISBN
  ORDER BY COUNT(ISBN) DESC
  )
WHERE rownum = 1
```